# Removing provisioning profiles from an iOs 10 device

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, provisioning-profile

I upload provisioning profiles to my iOs devices using iTunes.
On my iPad, still running iOs 7, it was possible to view and remove provisioning
profiles under Settings->General->Profiles.
I know Apple removed that feature with iOs 8 so of course it's gone from my iOs 10.3.1 device.
Now I'm having a hard time trying to remove unwanted or old provisioning profiles.

Things I've tried:

An old windows tool called 'iPhone configuration utility'. Though it lists the installed provisioning profiles just fine as soon as I press the 'remove' button I get an error message saying: 'A file operation failed'.

On a Mac I've installed Xcode 7.2.1 - the last version supporting Yosemite.
If I navigate to View->Devices->right-click my device->Show provisioning profiles, it says: 'No provisioning profiles installed'.

I'm a bit lost now. How do I get rid of provisioning profiles?

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach should work.  Make sure you have told your iOS device to trust the Mac when you plug it in.  I just tried on an iOS 10.3.2 device to go into the Devices window in Xcode 7.2.1.  I right-clicked the device and selected Show Provisioning profiles.  From there, I was able to see and remove provisioning profiles.  I would restart the iOS device and the Mac abd try this again, because it is certainly the Apple-approved way to manage the profiles on the device.

One question is why you would need to remove a provisioning profile. iOS has gotten much better about ensuring that if you have a newer profile, the old one should not interfere.  The only possible reason I could think of would be to prevent some internal app from running on a device.